# Error in ggplot when making a forest-plot resulting in NULL

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-forestplot

Trying to create a forest-plot in R using ggplot2 but running into some errors.

**Data**:

```
structure(list(explanatory_variables = structure(1:15, levels = c("Age", 
"Disease duration", "Smoking", "BMI", "HLA-B27", "Uveitis", "TNFi start year", 
"csDMARD", "CRP", "Psoriasis", "Arthritis", "NSAID", "Enthesitis", 
"TNFi type", "IBD"), class = "factor"), unadj_coef = c(0.93, 
0.92, 1.13, 1, 1.02, 1.32, 0.93, 0.83, 0.76, 1.42, 1.77, 0.04, 
1.26, 0.93, 1.3), adj_coef = c(0.91, 0.91, 1.13, 1, 1.02, 1.33, 
0.92, 0.83, 0.76, 1.42, 1.77, 0.04, 1.26, 0.93, 1.3), pct_change = c(-1.8, 
-0.9, 0.6, -0.5, 0.4, 0.3, -0.2, -0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, -0.1, -0.1, 
0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = "data.frame")
```

Code I have tried so far

```
# Sort data.frame by pct change
basdai_data <- basdai_data[order(abs(basdai_data$pct_change), decreasing = TRUE),]
basdai_data

# Reorder levels of explanatory variable
basdai_data$explanatory_variables  <- factor(basdai_data$explanatory_variables , levels = as.character(basdai_data$explanatory_variables ))
breaks <- as.character(levels(basdai_data$explanatory_variables))
breaks
basdai_data$explanatory_variables

# Create forest plot
ggplot(basdai_data, aes(x = pct_change, y = explanatory_variables)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed") +
  scale_y_discrete(breaks = breaks, labels = breaks) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(-3, 3, 1)) +
  labs(x = "Percentage change", y = "Explanatory variable") +
  theme_pubr() +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 15, family = "Calibri"),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 20))
```

This is my error:

```
"Error in ans[ypos] <- rep(yes, length.out = len)[ypos] : replacement has length zero
In addition: Warning message:
In rep(yes, length.out = len) : 'x' is NULL so the result will be NULL"
```

My expectation was a forest-plot with on the left side of the y-axis the names of the explanatory variables, on the x-axis the percentage change, at 0 a dashed vertical line. However, instead I received the error above.

My questions are actually two-folded: how do I fix the error and as a bonus, would it be possible to add 4 columns of data ("explanatory_variable", "unadjusted coef.", "adjusted coef.", "pct. change" before the forest-plot? That would be perfect. The data is also present in the data-set.

**EDITED**: I want to show my new data.frame and code to Allan because I am receiving an error "Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale" when applying his new code to p2. I added an extra column called "interaction". P1 works fine, but p2 not.

```
#Analysis of level 3 data
basdai_level3 <- structure(list(explanatory_variables = c("Age", "TNFi type", 
                                                          "TNFi start year", "CRP", "Smoking", "Disease duration", "HLA-B27", 
                                                          "NSAID", "csDMARD", "BMI", "Uveitis", "Psoriasis", "IBD", "Arthritis", 
                                                          "Enthesitis"), ID = c(11753, 11753, 11753, 8661, 9991, 8063, 
                                                                                7074, 5204, 6776, 6585, 5635, 5541, 5601, 3955, 4903), 
                                countries = c(15, 15, 15, 13, 14, 11, 14, 10, 15, 13, 10, 10, 10, 9, 9), 
                                unadj_coef = c(0.67, 0.67, 0.67, 0.38, 0.84, 0.59, 0.78, -0.2, 0.66, 0.75, 1.1, 1.2, 1.08, 1.56, 1.03), 
                                adj_coef = c(0.61, 0.67, 0.66, 0.38, 0.86, 0.56, 0.79, -0.2, 0.65, 0.74, 1.12, 1.2, 1.08, 1.57, 1.03), 
                                change = c(-0.06, 0, 0, 0, 0.02, -0.03, 0.02, 0, -0.01, -0.01, 0.02, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
                                pct_change = c(-8.9, 0.4, -0.4, 1.2, 2.3, -4.7, 2.3, -0.4, -1.3, -1.4, 1.4, 0.4, -0.1, 0.2, -0.4), 
                                unadj_coef_pvalue = c(0.037, 0.037, 0.037, 0.319, 0.016, 0.138, 0.054, 0.689, 0.125, 0.072, 0.017, 0.01, 0.02, 0.004, 0.039), 
                                adj_coef_pvalue = c(0.058, 0.037, 0.038, 0.314, 0.013, 0.158, 0.048, 0.69, 0.13, 0.076, 0.016, 0.01, 0.02, 0.003, 0.039), 
                                interaction = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -2.46, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5.07, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 15L), class = "data.frame")

#Sort data
basdai_level3 <- basdai_level3[order((basdai_level3$pct_change), decreasing = TRUE),]
basdai_level3

# Reorder levels of explanatory variable
basdai_level3$explanatory_variables  <- factor(basdai_level3$explanatory_variables , levels = as.character(basdai_level3$explanatory_variables ))
breaks <- as.character(levels(basdai_level3$explanatory_variables))

p2 <- ggplot(basdai_level3, aes(x = 1, y = explanatory_variables)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 2 * 1:8 - 1, linewidth = 13, color = "gray92") +
  geom_text(aes(label = explanatory_variables), hjust = 0) +
  geom_text(aes(x = 3, label = unadj_coef)) +
  geom_text(aes(x = 4, label = adj_coef)) +
  geom_text(aes(x = 5, label = pct_change)) +
  geom_text(aes(x = 6, label = interaction)) +
  scale_x_continuous(NULL, breaks = c(1, 3, 4, 5, 6), limits = c(1, 7),
                     labels = c('Variable', 'Unadj. coef.', 'Adj. coef.',
                                'Change (%)', 'Interaction'), position = 'top') +
  theme_void() +
  theme(axis.text.x.top = element_text(hjust = c(0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5),
                                       face = 2,  family = "Calibri"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your percentage change is not in the order you specified because you are sorting by the *absolute* value of percentage change. You can simply do:

```r
basdai_data <- basdai_data[order(basdai_data$pct_change, decreasing = TRUE),]
```

You are getting the error simply because you have not included any data layers. If you add a `geom_point`, the result is:

```r
ggplot(basdai_data, aes(x = pct_change, y = explanatory_variables)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_discrete(breaks = breaks, labels = breaks) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(-3, 3, 1)) +
  labs(x = "Percentage change", y = "Explanatory variable") +
  theme_pubr() +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 15, family = "Calibri"),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 20))
```

[image]

To get a table on the left side of the plot, you could do something like:

```r
p1 <- ggplot(basdai_data, aes(x = pct_change, y = explanatory_variables)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 2 * 1:8 - 1, linewidth = 13, color = "gray92") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_discrete(breaks = breaks, labels = breaks) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(-3, 3, 1)) +
  labs(x = "Percentage change", y = "Explanatory variable") +
  theme_pubr() +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 15, family = "Calibri"),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 20),
        axis.line.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank())

p2 <- ggplot(basdai_data, aes(x = 1, y = explanatory_variables)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 2 * 1:8 - 1, linewidth = 13, color = "gray92") +
  geom_text(aes(label = explanatory_variables), hjust = 0) +
  geom_text(aes(x = 3, label = unadj_coef)) +
  geom_text(aes(x = 4, label = adj_coef)) +
  geom_text(aes(x = 5, label = pct_change)) +
  scale_y_discrete(breaks = breaks, labels = breaks) +
  scale_x_continuous(NULL, breaks = c(1, 3, 4, 5), limits = c(1, 5.5),
                     labels = c('Variable', 'Unadjusted coef', 'Adj. coef',
                                '% change'), position = 'top') +
  theme_void() +
  theme(axis.text.x.top = element_text(hjust = c(0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5),
                                       face = 2))

library(patchwork)

p2 + p1
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! You did solve my first question. For whatever reason, I ordered the data.frame in my code from largest point estimate to smallest but in the graph it is unordered (as in your example). Why is this? How to solve it?

Comment: @Pashtun my original graph was sorted by the absolute value of percentage change, because that is what your code specified. If you just want to sort by percentage change, remove `abs`. I have updated to demonstrate.

Comment: thank you for this amazing post and work. When I try your code, the p1 and p2 graphs are formed as expected. However, when trying to join them I get the error `Can't add `p1` to a ggplot object.`. Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: @Pashtun did you install the patchwork package and use `library(patchwork)` as in my code example?

Comment: No I missed that, apologies, now it is working perfectly. Amazing! Thank you so much.

Comment: sorry to be so bold as to ask this, but would it be possible to adjust the code and have every two rows color "white" and "light grey" repeatedly (checkboard pattern)? This would significantly improve horizontal comparison. Many thanks for considering my request.

Comment: Cameraon. Thanks again. Please see my edited response. The p1 graph works fine but p2 now is a problem. I actually added an extra column, possibly why.

Comment: @Pashtun it looks like you didn't copy my code correctly again - you missed the `scale_y_discrete` line. Perhaps just copy-paste the block?